# Microsecond pulses with Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, wiringpi, pi4j

Trying to output 10 mhz pulses with Raspberry Pi/pi4j, wiringPi...

No problem with millisecond pulses

This works on Mac...doesn't work on Raspberry Pi with pi4j and wiringpi installed:

```
final long INTERVAL = 100;
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long end=0;
        do{
            end = System.nanoTime();
        }while(start + INTERVAL >= end);
        System.out.println(end - start);
```

Comment: ??? Something more about this? Some explanation what you would like to achieve?

Comment: If your problem is that you can't get 0.1 µS resolution, see the [documentation for nanotime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()), which says you get nanosecond precision but unspecified resolution.

Comment: On my Pi Zero, back-to-back calls to nanotime() give a difference of 6 to 8 µS !  The difference is always an integral number of µS (i.e., last 3 digits of difference in nS are 000) which suggests we have no better than µS resolution,

Comment: Thanks...I think that I was wrong and the code above was really working.  Unspecified resolution is a reality!